# Chart that plot data together for each loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use this code to plot data on the same chart for each loop. But it seems the chart is only plotting one excel workbook data and not the others. Or the plot for each loop is being removed on the chart before the next loop. What I want to do is to plot the data for each loop in the same chart together.

```
Option Explicit  Public Sub PlotGraph() 
    Dim fileName As String 
    Dim myFilePath As String
    Dim Wkbk As Workbook
    Dim myChart As Chart 
    Set myChart = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ChartObjects(1).Chart 

    myFilePath = "C:\Users\asdeff\Desktop\y\"
    fileName = Dir(myFilePath)

    While fileName <> vbNullString 
        Debug.Print fileName
        Set Wkbk = Workbooks.Open(myFilePath & fileName) 

        With myChart 
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries '
            .SeriesCollection(1).Name = fileName
            .SeriesCollection(1).Values = "[" & fileName & "]NPVExcelSheet1!$AX$4:$AX$45" 
            .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "[" & fileName & "]NPVExcelSheet1!$AY$4:$AY$45" 'The chart should use the data from the open Wkbk
        End With


        fileName = Dir                           
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The data for a chart needs to be in a worksheet somewhere. You are looping through several workbooks and with each iteration of the loop you are changing the data source for the SAME series in the chart.

If you want to create a chart with multiple series from multiple workbooks, that approach will never fly.

The chart will need to have a separate data source for each series. You may want to copy the data for each series to the workbook that hosts the chart, then add each new series to the chart as the data is coming in to the workbook.

I'm not even trying to give you code for that. You need to re-think your approach and understand how a chart and the underlying data works. Then you can write code to populate the data source for your chart.